# Django Model Inheritance: Duplicated class fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django project whereby every model inherits from a common "Object" model - which defines only two fields - the ID of the object (so every object in the entire system has a unique identifier) and a "type". The type is the type of object that particular instance is. This is a sort of "denormalized" field, making it faster to travel down the tree from Object to Person, for example.

Basically I have a field in one of the inherited models, which has the same name as another class that inherits from Object - that means that the field for travelling down the relationship is overridden.

I just wondered if anyone else has had a similar experience, and whether there are any rather elegant ways of solving it - other than just renaming the field in the inherited model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe renaming would be appropriate. If one of your fields has the same identifier as a class, you may break some naming conventions (although, of course these are only conventions).

See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), section *Naming Conventions*.

```
Class Names

  Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.
  Classes for internal use have a leading underscore in addition.


Method Names and Instance Variables

  Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
  underscores as necessary to improve readability.
```